# Re-arrange a table in R

Tags: r, sorting, reformat

I'm reading a .dat file in R which has 10,800 rows and 6 columns (I'll leave you the [link to the file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1l31Khe7HOc8LDMHQkg4f_4UI3s0tr5g-) if you want to take a look )

In order to read it I use this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

tryon <- read.table("F:/1981_01_NAM.dat", header=FALSE)
```

Once I have that table I want to re-arrange it making an array or matrix that has 360 rows and 180 columns.
For example I have this:

```
   [1]   [2]  [3]

[1]1     2     3
[2]4    5      6
[3]7    8      9
```

And I want this:

```
   [1]   [2]  [3]  [4]   [5]  [6]

[1]1     2     3   4   5   6
[3]7    8      9   ...
```

So by following some examples I used:

```
lon = 360
lat = 180

output2 <- matrix(unlist(tryon), nrow = lon, ncol= lat, byrow = TRUE)
```

But it does not do what I want, if you use the data I linked above, after the re-arrange the value at the position [1,35] should be   -0.00367983, but I get a 0.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: you need to include the `t()` function. try `matrix(t(unlist(tyron)),lon,byrow=T)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just try to use `unlist(tyron)`, you'll see that it doesn't do anything because matrices aren't lists. So you'll have to turn it into a list, and then `unlist` it which effectively turns it into a single vector. *Then* you can use the matrix function to turn it back into a matrix.

```
is.list(mat)
FALSE
```

try:

```
output2 <- matrix(unlist(as.list(tyron)), nrow = lon, ncol = lat, byrow = TRUE)
```